# Want to update parent lookup list from child based on lookup selection/deselection

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp

I have two sharepoint lists, Asset Detail (parent) and Asset Assignment (child) list. on Asset Assignment I have a field where I select multiple Asset items, so at the asset assignment side, I can assign multiple assets items to a record.

Now my requirement is once a item from parent list has been used in child, that item shouldn't be available in the lookup to select. Understand the scenario like there is one single asset which can assign to someone, if that asset has been assigned then it shouldn't be available in the lookup for further use or assignment.

I have implemented the scenario where on parent list I've created a column called status, which specify whether current item is `Assigned` or `Ideal`. but I stuck with the update part, how can I update the parent list every time child item created and modified with the assignment lookup. so if I remove an item in lookup from asset assignment, then it should update the corresponding item in parent list as `ideal`, or in case of assignment it should update the parent item field as `Assigned`.

Any solution which I can use, I tried flow but stuck with the update part how should be the logic. other alternative could be powerapp.

Answer (score 0):

There is a action called update item in Flow. Set the trigger to be when an item is created or modified. Then update the item with the id of item in lookup column. For removing item in assest assignment, you can create another flow which is triggered by when an item is deleted.
[image: Flow sample]

Comment: Appreciates your help here, but in my case child list (Asset assignment) have that parent lookup as multiselect picker, and second let's assume, one of the item has been modified and initially there was 2 values in asset lookup but now one value has been removed and instead of that another one is added, so in a same operation, one of the lookup value has been removed and other one added, so how can we accommodate that behavior. I hope you understand my scenario here

Comment: @user2809299 sorry for the delay. Just want to confirm, the final goal of the choice column will be like this: when the user edit the column, he can always add or remove assests. After that, the parent list will automatically change the corresponding Assets to assigned or ideal, correct?

Comment: Yes @jerry you are correct in understanding that

Comment: @user2809299 I think it will be hard to use flow or powerapps to do that without code. The modified trigger will not provide previous value of the item in the child list. So it will be tough to find the way to update the assignment. You can vote for this:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/Modified-trigger-should-give-previous-values-for-fields-changed/idi-p/94078 to make available in the future.

Comment: Now it seems bad, I regret my own decision without that it will be a very tedious task to implement. I could have chosen a different platform to build that process.